# Kill process that is taking specific port

Tags: bash, shell

Is is possible to programatically select process that is taking a specific port (:3000 for example) and kill it ?

I do that by hand now by using

```
netstat -tp
```

and then I would check pid of a process and kill it using `kill` command.

I want to write a shell script that would do that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your system, your `fuser` command may be able to do this:

```
fuser -k [-<SIGNAL>] <port>/<proto>
fuser -n <proto> -k [-<SIGNAL>] <port>
```

Examples :

```
fuser -k 12345/tcp
fuser -n udp -k -KILL 23456
```

On the command line, you may also want to execute `fuser -v <port>/<proto>` first, to see what you are going to kill.